Word Override Table Formatting with Header Formatting
I'm trying to create a header format in word such that I can apply it to each table. So far, I have a header called "Table Header". For the most part, it works. For example, I can go into the Styles Pane, click on "Modify Header", and modify the header such that the font is bolded, and it will work (as shown below). With that being said, when I try to change the font size, it does not work. For example, if I try to change the font from 12 to 20, press "OK" and then reopen the "Modify Style" window, it will be back at 12.
I believe it is because there is some table formatting that is overriding the font size. With that being said, I'm not sure how to get rid of this table formatting or let the header formatting take precedence over it.
Styles Pane
Modify Header Window
I've already tried deleting the "Normal Style" and it won't let me.
